# Is $x^3$ uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Intuition by Lipschitz Continuity makes me think so, but I'm not sure how to apply the definition of UC to prove this. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: We assume a and b are real numbers and a < b.

Comment: You mean that a theorem that says that any continuos function on a bounded interval looks like a polynomial tells you something about whether a specific polynomial is uniformly continuous?

Comment: I forgot just how much of a prick some people on MSE can be

Comment: Yeah, looking at it now I agree I crossed a line there. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m:=\max (|a|,|b|);$

$|x^3-y^3|=|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|\le$

$|x-y|(|x^2+y^2| +|xy|)\lt$

$|x-y|(3m^2)$.

Choose $\delta =\dfrac{\epsilon}{3m^2}.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x^3$ has a bounded derivative on $(a,b)$ so it is Lipschitz continuous and thus uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Your function extends continuously to $[a,b]$. And any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.